# Error in using as.POSIXct function

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series

HI I am trying to put a vector of dates as input for the function but I am getting NA. It works if it doesn't have the full timestamp.

```
 as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
 [1] NA

as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S", tz='GMT')
[1] NA
```

Comment: You need `%p` parameter to specify the `pm` part. `as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S")` should work.

Comment: still getting the same result. It used to work but all of sudden I am keep getting NAs...

Comment: That's interesting because it is working for me on Mac. You may try to restart your R session or RStudio? Working on Windows also.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi hmm. Not sure then. Probably `Ubuntu`?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: or maybe it depends on the time-zone of the machine? Have you tried: `as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S", tz='GMT')`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I'm using a 24 hr clock as well & for me its working

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Just tested my `Ubuntu` 14.04, working as well.

Comment: Try running ` Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")` to see what locale R is using. The pm part of the date will be sensitive to this.

Comment: K i am still getting this NA I just reinstalled R and still getting NAs...